How do I tell when print to sys.stdout in Python has failed?
In the following program I can handle the OSError exception if I open /dev/full myself, but if I use shell redirection it seems as though io.TextIOWrapper swallows the OSError and there's no way for the program to detect the print failed.
How can I detect when print to sys.stdout has failed?
#! /usr/bin/env python3.12

import sys

try:
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        out = open(sys.argv[1], 'w', buffering=1)
    else:
        out = sys.stdout
    print("call...", file=sys.stderr)
    print("data", file=out)
    print("return...", file=sys.stderr)
    #out.close()
except OSError as e:
    print(f"error: {e}", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

$ ./ftest.py /dev/full
call...
error: [Errno 28] No space left on device
$ ./ftest.py > /dev/full
call...
return...
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device


Fwiw: the docs for sys.stdout say this: "When interactive, the stdout stream is line-buffered. Otherwise, it is block-buffered like regular text files. ". I also tried the code here, with flush=True in the second print call; that does output "error: [Errno 28] No space left on device" when using > /dev/full, and doesn't print return..., but also prints the Exception ignored line and the default error message OSError: <...> below it.

You need to manually flush output buffer after your print and catch any exception thats occurs during flush:
import sys

try:
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        out = open(sys.argv[1], 'w', buffering=1)
    else:
        out = sys.stdout
    print("call...", file=sys.stderr)
    print("data",file=out)
    out.flush()  # MANUALLY FLUSH
    print("return...", file=sys.stderr)
except OSError as e:
    print(f"error: {e}",file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

This happens because when you redirectt sys.stdout to faulty device /dev/full, the print writes to internal buffer without immediately raising error.
Also you could try to unbuffered output:
$ PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ./ftest.py > /dev/full

Or even reconfigure sys.stdout:
sys.stdout.reconfigure(line_buffering=True)

